# Create a MAVEN respository

Tags: java, maven

I wish to create an internal maven repository on my network. Can anyone show me how to have this done ?

Comment: What is the purpose of this internal maven repository, for artefacts confined only?

Answer (score 3):

Check out these open-source managers:

- [Nexus](https://www.sonatype.com/products/repository-oss)
- [Archiva](https://archiva.apache.org/)
- [Artifactory](https://jfrog.com/artifactory/)
- [Reposilite](https://reposilite.com/)

Full list (with also commercial versions):

- [Repository Management Software](https://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Maven Repository Managers such as Nexus: http://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html

Also have a look at how to configure your settings file:
http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/maven-sect-single-group.html

Comment: Why the down-vote? Please add a comment when you down-vote.

Answer (score -1):

You are thinking of a deploying a [Nexus Repository](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/).